# How does one access the event log from SMBios' "System Event Log" (Type 15) structure when the access method is '4'?

Tags: bios, firmware

I'm trying to go through the system event log that is stored by the firmware, and which is pointed to by the "System Event Log" structure within the SMBios table. As far as I understand, this table describes where to look for the events (there's an address field) and how to look for them (there's an 'access method' field in he structure).

This 'access method' field is an integer that is code for one of 4 different access methods, like I/O ports and memory maps. But I have a problem with the value I'm getting, which is '4' . According to the spec, '4' means "Available through General-Purpose NonVolatile Data functions" . What are those general-Purpose NonVolatile Data functions and how does one use them?

Comment: I see nothing in the SMBIOS specification that would help to answer your question.  My guess is that the functions are proprietary.

Comment: Oops.  I missed the text that says that when the Access Method is 0x04, the Access Method Address field contains the GPNV Handle.  You need to look at an older version of the SMBIOS spec (http://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0119.pdf) for information about how to use the handle.